# Why is my code showing error Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was trying to implement preorder traversal in a binary tree. This is my code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
   int data;
   struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
};

struct node *root= NULL;

struct node *inorder_search(struct node *node, int val){
   inorder_search(node->left,val);
   if(node->data==val)   return node;
   inorder_search(node->right,val);
}

void insert(int data1, int data2, char subtree){
   struct node *current;
   struct node *temp1;
   struct node *temp2;

   temp1->data= data1;
   temp1->left= NULL;
   temp1->right= NULL;

   temp2->data= data2;
   temp2->left= NULL;
   temp2->right= NULL;

   if(root==NULL){
      root= temp1;
      if(subtree=='R'){
         root->right= temp2;
         return;
      }
      else{
         root->left= temp2;
         return;
      }
   }
   else{
      current= inorder_search(root,data1);
      if(subtree=='R'){
         current->right= temp2;
         return;
      }
      else{
         current->left= temp2;
         return;
       }
     }
   }

void preorder_traversal(struct node *node){
    if(node==NULL)   return;
    cout<<node->data<<" ";
    preorder_traversal(root->left);
    preorder_traversal(root->right);
}

int main(void){
   int edges;//edges= no. of edges
   cout<<"Enter the number of edges: ";
   cin>>edges;

   int i;
   int relations= edges*3;
   int *arr= new int[relations+1]; //since input is in the form 1 2 R 1 2 L where R= right subtree, L= left subtree
   for(i=0; i<relations;i++)  cin>>arr[i];

   for(i=0;i<relations;i+=3) insert(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]);

   preorder_traversal(root);
}
```

The code is for the following input type

```
1 2 L 1 3 R
```

The function insert(), I am trying to create a tree for the input which has been taken in the form of an array. The function inorder_search() is used to search for the particular node to whose left or right subtree the data is to be added, which is returned to the insert() function. For example in 1 2 L 1 3 R , '1' is the node to which '2' and '3' are the left and right subtree respectively. So I search for '1' in the inorder_search() function and return the node to which '2' or '3' is inserted accordingly in the insert() function.

Can someone explain where exactly I am going wrong and if there is a better way to implement it?

Comment: Is it an assignment?

Comment: Use a debugger and inspect the core dump. Where (stacktrace) is it crashing?

Comment: No allocation anywhere. You're sure about that `insert`? Either way, this is more C than C++.

Comment: Compile: `gcc -Wall -Werror -g`  Debug: `gdb ./myprog`

Comment: Look for the places where you allocate the nodes.

Comment: @RawN this is not an assignment

Comment: @Code Bunny Function inorder_search has an infinite recursion.

Comment: Your "[mcve]" isn't complete - either provide the required input values, or (better) incorporate suitable constant values into your test program.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you compiled with warnings turned off.  When I compiled this, I got the following messages:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Weffc++     38307710.cpp   -o 38307710
38307710.cpp: In function ‘node* inorder_search(node*, int)’:
38307710.cpp:16:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
38307710.cpp: In function ‘void insert(int, int, char)’:
38307710.cpp:23:22: warning: ‘temp1’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    temp1->data= data1;
                      ^
38307710.cpp:27:22: warning: ‘temp2’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    temp2->data= data2;
                      ^
```

Furthermore, running under Valgrind gives

```
==5113== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5113==    at 0x40093C: insert(int, int, char) (38307710.cpp:23)
==5113==    by 0x400B77: main (38307710.cpp:72)
==5113== 
==5113== Invalid write of size 4
==5113==    at 0x40093C: insert(int, int, char) (38307710.cpp:23)
==5113==    by 0x400B77: main (38307710.cpp:72)
==5113==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5113== 
==5113== 
==5113== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5113==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==5113==    at 0x40093C: insert(int, int, char) (38307710.cpp:23)
==5113==    by 0x400B77: main (38307710.cpp:72)
```

which indicates precisely where you first access invalid values.